# i'm struggling to define yVelocity within my code

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to programming so i am learning html, css and javascript. so i decided to challenge myself to make the game Snake. I am trying to define the yVelocity to allow me to move the snake but when i run the code it is saying yVelocity is not defined but when i write it in vs code everything seems to be correct to my knowledge. if anyone could help me that would be great :) [image of the code i have written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRbMc.png)

[the error i am recieving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OC4I.png)

Comment: Thanks for asking here! Generally, the community asks that you paste your actual code here rather than a link to a screenshot!

Comment: Looks like you're treating `yVelocity` as a global variable. Where in your code are you initially defining and setting it? It would be really helpful if you can drop the code in https://plnkr.co/ or https://codepen.io/ and share a link.

Comment: @Nick I am very new here and I didnt really know what i was doing when i posted the question so apologies for anything I have done wrong, im very new to the world of programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a beginner that's a good start! You have a lot of potential. For your issue try adding `let yVelocity = [your value]` somewhere above your functions. I'm not seeing it in the image.

Comment: Thank you! much appreciated, ive been putting alot of time into it haha! and i figured out my issue not long after i posted this. i had a spacing error where i defined yVelocity. i had written

letyVelocity = 0; instead of 

let yVelocity = 0;

which is why everything seemed right because it was haha